# addEventListener "activating" automatically

Tags: javascript

Basic question I know, but I'm having trouble understanding something. I have a function that simulates a dice throw, with the number of faces as the parameter :

```
function throw(faces){
//My function here
}
```

I then have buttons to simulate those launches with different numbers, and I want them to launch `throw` when they are clicked :

```
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click",throw(4));
document.getElementById("6").addEventListener("click",throw(6));
```

Etc.

But when I launch the CodePen ([here](https://codepen.io/ArnaudStephan/pen/OxrBBz?editors=0010)), the functions launch automatically (with the correct parameters though) and then I can't click the buttons. Well I can, but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling it's a very basic stuff, but I can't seem to get it. I've seen that if you put `throw` instead of `throw()` the function doesn't launch automatically, but how am I supposed to change the parameters then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw(4)` executes/calls the method automatically because you are invoking the function/method using `()`. If you want the event listener on the button to call `throw(4)` when clicked, then use the following:

```
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click", function(){
   throw(4);
});
```

or

```
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click", throw);
function throw (){
  console.log(event.target.id); //event.target.id will give the id of the element clicked
  // your rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `throw` function needs to return a function to the `addEventListener`. For example:

```
function throw ( faces ) {
    return function () {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * faces );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to return a new function with a preset `this` keyword and arguments (`null` in this case):

```
function throw(faces){
  // My function here
}

document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click", throw.bind(null, 4));
document.getElementById("6").addEventListener("click", throw.bind(null, 6));
```

Or define a new function inside which executes `throw`:

```
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    throw(4);
});
document.getElementById("6").addEventListener("click", function() {
    throw(6);
});
```